# можно ли через props передавать async/await функции?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

можно ли через `props в react` передавать `async/await` функции?

Comment: props - всего лишь аргументы функции (React компонента). Так что через них, как и через любые аргументы функции, можно передавать все что угодно, в т.ч. и другие функции (неважно какие). Контекст использования все равно определяете вы сами.

Answer (score 0):

Можно передавать любые параметры через пропсы, включая async/await функции. Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).